# Controllers, in different Areas, with the same name. Can Castle Windsor handle this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

Let's say I have two controllers with the same name (i.e., HomeController).  The first is in the standard Controller directory (~\Controllers) and the second is in an Area (~\Area\AreaName\Controllers).

Can Castle Windsor handle this type of scenario?  What steps do I need to complete to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that they have the same name should make no difference, as they are different types, and container registration is by type.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that when I try to display the Index View from "~\Area\AreaName\Controllers\HomeController\Index" it is hitting the Index Action of that Controller, then trying to load some methods in "~\Controllers\HomeController".  This only happens when my return type is ActionResult.  When the return type is string everything works fine.  It appears my mapping is correct but it doesn't like the ActionResult return type in "~\Area\AreaName\Controllers\HomeController\Index".  This is confusing I know.  Appreciate the help.